# borrowed data escapes outside of closure

Tags: rust

I created two structs, `Car` and `CarModifier`. Both `Car` and `CarModifier` are instantiated in `main.rs`. `CarModifier` modifies one of the fields of `Car` using data from curl request. Here is the code:

`main.rs`

```rust
use sample::{car::Car, car_modifier::CarModifier};

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let mut car = Car::new();
    let mut car_modifier = CarModifier::new();
    car_modifier.update_car(&mut car);

    println!("{:?}", car.driver);
}
```

`Car.rs`

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Car<'a> {
    pub driver: &'a [u8]
}

impl<'a> Car<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            driver: &[26]
        }
    }

    pub fn update_driver(&mut self, new_driver: &'a [u8]) {
        self.driver = new_driver;
    }
}
```

`CarModifier.rs`

```rust
use curl::easy::Easy;
use crate::{car::Car};

pub struct CarModifier;

impl CarModifier {

    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
        }
    }

    pub fn update_car(&mut self, car: &mut Car) {
        let mut easy = Easy::new();
        easy.url("https://www.rust-lang.org/").unwrap();
        let mut transfer = easy.transfer();

        transfer.write_function(|data: &[u8]| {
            car.update_driver(data);
            Ok(data.len())
        }).unwrap();
        transfer.perform().unwrap();
    }

}
```

This is the error which I get when trying to run

```rust
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of closure
  --> src/car_modifier.rs:19:13
   |
13 |     pub fn update_car(&mut self, car: &mut Car) {
   |                                  --- `car` declared here, outside of the closure body
...
18 |         transfer.write_function(|data: &[u8]| {
   |                                  ---- `data` is a reference that is only valid in the closure body
19 |             car.update_driver(data);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `data` escapes the closure body here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0521`.
error: could not compile `sample` due to previous error
```

I seem to understand from the error that `data` lives only in the closure body and the code tries to refer that in `car.driver` which will outlive the closure body, hence the error. Is this the right understanding?
I am also aware that instead of using &[u8], I could use Vec<u8> to resolve the error. But how can I keep using &[u8]?

Comment: I don't think you can? `Vec` puts the data on the heap, which lets `car` reference it, whereas your array is allocated on the stack. (I think - I might be wrong!)

Comment: You understanding is correct. Not only does that data only live for the lifetime of the closure, but the whole curl request only last as long as the body of `fn update_car`, so there's just no way to keep that data around without copying it somewhere else (like into a `Vec<u8>` owned by `Car`).

Answer (score 0):

Basically `data` belongs to the curl library. It may be a slice of some library internal buffer pool, and may be re-used for some other curl api calls later on, or freed after this call. You need to copy `data` into the `Car` structure instead of just having a pointer to the underlying buffer. Rust compiler helps you to catch that problem. In `C++` the compiler won't even tell you this error and the C++ code will have runtime problems.